# Rails 5 before_destroy callback: with prepend or without fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I know that in Rails 5 `before_destroy` callback does not take into account `false` return value but `throw(:abort)` instead. You can find more about it [here](https://dev.mikamai.com/2017/01/12/how-requirements-shaped-my-code-aka-rails-5-and/) and [there](https://medium.com/appaloosa-store-engineering/caution-when-using-before-destroy-with-model-association-71600b8bfed2) and in [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-set_callback).

But `prepend` option still does not work in the following situation.
I need to prevent the deletion of a last record in the following model:

```
class ShopLanguage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :language
  has_many :descriptions, inverse_of: :shop_language, dependent: :destroy

  validates :language, :shop, presence: true
  validates :language, uniqueness: { scope: :shop, message: "already defined for this shop"}

  before_destroy :check_last_language, prepend: true


  private

  def check_last_language 
    if shop.languages.count < 2
      errors[:base] << "You can't delete the last language"
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Here is Shop model:

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :links, inverse_of: :shop
  has_many :shop_languages, inverse_of: :shop, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :languages, through: :shop_languages
...
```

Even if I move the callback upper just before declaring the relations:

```
class ShopLanguage < ApplicationRecord
  before_destroy :check_last_language, prepend: true
...
```

it does not work either. Here is what I tried in a rails console:

```
shop = Shop.first
#<Shop id: 2, category: "Sport", fax: nil, identifier: 1, leader: "XXXXX", modified_by: "batch.update.shops", name: "ENGLOS", opening_date: "1976-07-27", phone: "0320001700", status: "open", created_at: "2018-03-22 16:39:35", updated_at: "2018-03-22 16:39:35"> 

2.4.0 :002 > lang = Language.find(245)
  Language Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "languages".* FROM "languages" WHERE "languages"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 245], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Language id: 245, tag: "fr-FR", created_at: "2018-03-22 16:25:59", updated_at: "2018-03-22 16:25:59"> 

shop.languages
  Language Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "languages".* FROM "languages" INNER JOIN "shop_languages" ON "languages"."id" = "shop_languages"."language_id" WHERE "shop_languages"."shop_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["shop_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Language id: 245, tag: "fr-FR", created_at: "2018-03-22 16:25:59", updated_at: "2018-03-22 16:25:59">]> 


shop.languages.delete(lang)
   (0.4ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM "shop_languages" WHERE "shop_languages"."shop_id" = $1 AND "shop_languages"."language_id" = 245  [["shop_id", 2]]
   (0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => [#<Language id: 245, tag: "fr-FR", created_at: "2018-03-22 16:25:59", updated_at: "2018-03-22 16:25:59">] 
2.4.0 :007 > shop.languages.size
   (3.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "languages" INNER JOIN "shop_languages" ON "languages"."id" = "shop_languages"."language_id" WHERE "shop_languages"."shop_id" = $1  [["shop_id", 2]]
 => 0
```

So, the callback hasn't been called.
The problem is that, as explained in [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html),

> 5 Skipping Callbacks Just as with validations, it is also possible to
>   skip callbacks by using the following methods:
>
> decrement decrement_counter delete delete_all

So, if I got it right, when I called `delete` on my collection:

```
shop.languages.delete(lang)
```

my callback method will never be called.
More of that, Active Record or Active Model callbacks no longer halt when returning false, so the only solution would be to use:

```
throw(:abort) if shop.languages.count < 2
```

The question is how to delete properly a record from the table `shop_languages` without deleting the corresponding language record in the table `languages`? Using
`throw(:abort) if ...` seems not to be enough readable and convenient way for an API response.

Comment: For Rails 5, after adding error use `throw(:abort)` instead of `false`. And If association has some depend destroy then use prepend option to run those validation before it.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't be sure if this will solve your problem but you could override `#destroy`:

```
def destroy
  if ...
    super
  else
    # no-op
  end
end
```

Comment: Should also override `destroy!` if doing this.

Comment: I think `destroy!` might call `destroy` and raise if it returns `false`.